# Failed to fetch the following dependencies: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.10

Tags: android, kotlin, unity-game-engine

I am using **Unity 2022.3.10f1** and **IronSource_IntegrationManager_v7.5.1** (yes, i am using unity LevelPlay for ads). When I try to resolve, error message appear. Message at console **"Failed to fetch the following dependencies: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.10"**.

I tried install manually jdk, sdk, ndk, gradle [here](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcodeprofessionally.com%2Funity-android-support-setup-jdk-sdk-ndk-gradle-for-all-versions%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0JF_KILOMnzrNvVLTiOCSLWIcahpesf_McZfCVS3BixBU_WQqm_dqgCNg%23google_vignette&h=AT1yvJNsfcWrcfemQw674VJM-OEVYpZ2Dq0lFPwm3ei2GiOuafIgqfN7Diez8TJfEqJEcSchH8XWK7yrI0rqDkyxPaOCr--FEq2jkA0QQuvIALx-JNG90XgfARyM05h8ySLiU5PcNNhryucgTYPQ&__tn__=-UK-R&c%5B0%5D=AT1cIu4N-peJGJvPqxfcgb48VlOMwQGLjAn7DCsWd8UJP09tN42PP7g5dNDQWIVlLH5EsFbIeyRcZtp-RbOxpKZBD7JRduI6j9rmVGVU7pwHVVa_wruBbkKBeM14ZgGqbak6A6tZAmKj4pvZ68UfpWipByfW7830yq12beX84JKh77GoegatAOt-d4HGbNttAmBk5zsYnKZytEfzOob_JbhzYVREDSR0W7DfAbJc-mhClA), installed GooglePlayGames plugin, messed with custom gradle files. But all I see is popup "failed" for the next 3 days of resolving again and again.

Here is full error at console

> Resolution failed
>
> Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.10
>
> 0x00007ff6081c282d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
> 0x00007ff6081c77d9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
> 0x00007ff609197831 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007ff609855d52 (Unity)
> DebugStringToFile 0x00007ff6070f6db6 (Unity)
> DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000027f44b2eaa3 (Mono JIT Code)
> (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
> 0x0000027f44b2e71b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
> 0x0000027f44b2e460 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x0000027fb45c5d45 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 0x0000027f44bc57fb (Mono JIT Code)
> Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) 0x0000027f4716163f (Mono
> JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log
> (string,Google.LogLevel) 0x0000027fb45c5ceb (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:LogMissingDependenciesError
> (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>) 0x0000027fb45c580b (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Google.JarResolver.Dependency>)
> 0x0000027fb45c4a71 (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__16
> () 0x0000027fb45c4064 (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__24
> () 0x0000027fa949f499 (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStorey17:<>m__21
> () 0x0000027f44bcb81d (Mono JIT Code)
> Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs () 0x0000027f44bc8b1b (Mono
> JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:m__A ()
> 0x0000027f44bc8906 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction
> (System.Action) 0x0000027f44bc876b (Mono JIT Code)
> Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll () 0x0000027f63c2e510 (Mono JIT
> Code) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
> 0x0000027fa907c115 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
> object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
> 0x00007ff8df51e274 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
> 0x00007ff8df45eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
> 0x00007ff8df45ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
> 0x00007ff6080d9d14 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff6080b7e34
> (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff6080b2a85 (Unity)
> ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff608201e6b (Unity)
> Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallUpdateFunctions
> 0x00007ff608c04817 (Unity) SceneTracker::Update 0x00007ff608d26e99
> (Unity) Application::TickTimer 0x00007ff60919e16a (Unity)
> MainMessageLoop 0x00007ff6091a39d0 (Unity) WinMain 0x00007ff60a587dbe
> (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007ff935697344 (KERNEL32)
> BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ff9358a26b1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

I also got a warning about dependencies conflicting (not sure if it relate to this problem)

> Some conflicting dependencies were found. The following dependency
> versions were modified:
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1 -->
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:+
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0 -->
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:+
> com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0 -->
> com.google.android.play:app-update:+
> com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0 -->
> com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.+
> com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01 -->
> com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:+
> com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.5.1 -->
> com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:+ com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.8.0 -->
> com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:adcolony-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:adcolony-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:admob-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:admob-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:applovin-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:applovin-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:facebook-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:facebook-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:ironsource-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:ironsource-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:mediation-sdk:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:mediation-sdk:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:unityads-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:unityads-adapter:+
> com.unity3d.mediation:vungle-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ -->
> com.unity3d.mediation:vungle-adapter:+
>
> 0x00007ff6081c282d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
> 0x00007ff6081c77d9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
> 0x00007ff609197831 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007ff609855d52 (Unity)
> DebugStringToFile 0x00007ff6070f6db6 (Unity)
> DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000027f44b2eaa3 (Mono JIT Code)
> (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
> 0x0000027f44b2e71b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
> 0x0000027f44b2e460 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x0000027fa94905a8 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object) 0x0000027f44bc575b (Mono JIT
> Code) Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) 0x0000027f4716163f
> (Mono JIT Code) GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log
> (string,Google.LogLevel) 0x0000027fa942f74b (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__18
> (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) 0x0000027fa942f535 (Mono JIT
> Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStoreyF/c__AnonStorey10:<>m__28
> () 0x0000027f44bc942a (Mono JIT Code)
> Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () 0x0000027f44bc8b03 (Mono JIT
> Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:m__A () 0x0000027f44bc8906
> (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
> 0x0000027f44bc876b (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll
> () 0x0000027f44bc6233 (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:Run
> (System.Action,bool) 0x0000027fa942f4b3 (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/c__AnonStoreyF:<>m__27
> (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) 0x0000027fa942f2c5 (Mono JIT
> Code) (wrapper delegate-invoke)
> :invoke_void_CommandLine/Result
> (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) 0x0000027fa942f1ea (Mono JIT
> Code)
> GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog/ProgressReporter:SignalComplete
> () 0x0000027fa942f19b (Mono JIT Code)
> GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog/ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion
> (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) 0x0000027fa942f0f5 (Mono JIT
> Code)
> GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/c__AnonStorey0/c__AnonStorey1:<>m__4
> () 0x0000027f44bc942a (Mono JIT Code)
> Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () 0x0000027f44bc8b03 (Mono JIT
> Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:m__A () 0x0000027f44bc8906
> (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
> 0x0000027f44bc876b (Mono JIT Code) Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll
> () 0x0000027f63c2e510 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
> 0x0000027fa907c115 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
> object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
> 0x00007ff8df51e274 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
> 0x00007ff8df45eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
> 0x00007ff8df45ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
> 0x00007ff6080d9d14 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff6080b7e34
> (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff6080b2a85 (Unity)
> ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff608201e6b (Unity)
> Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallUpdateFunctions
> 0x00007ff608c04817 (Unity) SceneTracker::Update 0x00007ff608d26e99
> (Unity) Application::TickTimer 0x00007ff60919e16a (Unity)
> MainMessageLoop 0x00007ff6091a39d0 (Unity) WinMain 0x00007ff60a587dbe
> (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007ff935697344 (KERNEL32)
> BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ff9358a26b1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

Any help would be appreciated a lot. Since I am totally hopeless right now. I have seen another person have the same issue at [github](https://discussions.unity.com/t/googleplayservices-gradleresolver-logmissingdependencieserror-org-jetbrains-kotlin-kotlin-bom/288734). But no one has any working answer yet.

Comment: it seems odd they use a jetbrains package..  have you tried installing it manually first?

Comment: @BugFinder I'm not sure, although I'm not a mobile developer, but jetbrains is an editor right? Like if I could download it package, then how can I set path to its dependencies? Maybe I could install kotlin instead? Because I think the resolver trying to access the internet to fetch these dependencies and just failed for no reason...

Comment: @BugFinder Oh, and some people suggested I check the custom gradle main. But when I do that, the resolve just does not build the files, and instantly appears the popup "resolution succeed". But when I check the folder in plugin/adroid/... I only can see my gradle files. (it's a fake popup)

Comment: well jetbrains is a company who make an editor but if you bother to google that package, you can download it.. It probably cant find it because they may have moved website,  or it only looks on github or who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Same set-up here. After 2 days of struggling my best guess is that it is a bug of the 7.5.1 iron source package.

I reverted to version 7.3.1 and build is successful now. But I have to say that I also tried a lot of other things (amongst others: Deleting complete Library folder of the project and reimporting all assets; updating External Dependencies Mangaer to version 1.2.177, deleting several gradle files etc.) and it is hard to say what did the trick. Anyway, a huge pain in the ass altogether. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I decided to leave it and use google admob instead. Since I don't think I can do anything further due to my skill. And it worked!